# Как организовать поиск типа like?

Tags: поиск, yii, like

Как модифицировать стандартный поиск, чтобы он смог искать в строке 1, 2, 3 что-то like подобное, типа 2, 3, или 2, или 1, 3? Вообще-то было б идеально, чтобы подсказали, как сделать поиск на основе чекбокслиста. Ну типа выбираем 1, 3 элемент и на основе его делаем поиск.

---

Фигота какая-то:

```
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('m_complect',$this->m_complect,true, 'LIKE');
```

Не проходит со значением 1, 3, 6 поиск 1, 6.

Нужен запрос вида

```
FROM
`tbl_motor`
 where `m_complect` like '%1%6%';
```

а он делает

```
 `tbl_motor`
 where `m_complect` like '%1,6%';
```

А если так менять, то вообще неправильно:

```
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('m_complect',str_replace(",", "%", $this->m_complect),true, 'LIKE');
```

Comment: @anunak, нормализуйте базу данных. Одно поле в базе данных - это минимальная, атомарная единица измерения. В ней не должно лежать нескоько сущностей (ссылок). Используйте для этого связанные таблицыю

Comment: пусть будет одна колонка. не хочу создавать доп таблицы или доп колонки. усложняет разработку. на данном этапе хочу переписать

 public function search()
 {
  // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

  $criteria->compare('m_id',$this->m_id);
  $criteria->compare('m_number',$this->m_number,true);
на что-то like подобное но не смекну как

Comment: @anunak

> не хочу создавать доп таблицы или доп колонки. усложняет разработку. 

![](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/r2d/images/9/92/Facepalm_stick_figure.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20140814175559)

ну что вы, я это говорю не потому, что прекрасно соображаю, к чему это приведет, и не потому, что вы сейчас в десятки раз увеличиваете технический долг.

Comment: > Одно поле в базе данных - это минимальная, атомарная единица измерения. 

[1НФ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0)

> ...усложняет разработку.

@anunak, скажите это старине Дейту.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720512/yii-how-to-organize-search-type-like/28721808#28721808